# Visual Studio Error When Creating New ASP.NET Web Application

Tags: visual-studio-2013, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, visual-studio-templates

I have successfully created Web API projects a few days ago using Visual Studio 2013 update 4. Today when I try to create a project using the same default project that comes with VS, I get this error:

```
Unspecified error (Expection from HRESULT: 0x80004005 (E_FAIL))
```

[image: Unspecified error (Expection from HRESULT: 0x80004005 (E_FAIL))]

Comment: I already tried restoring the templates as suggested here but no luck... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms247116%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. In my case, my company maps my documents folder where the templates are stored to a network share and I was not connected to the VPN. Oh silly day.